Ruby poisonous emoji character?
I have Ruby 3.3.4 installed on MacOS 14.6.1.
Suppose I have this string in the shell:
$ st="02☺️468"
$ echo "$st"
02☺️468

If I now feed that string into Ruby, I get the second emoji broken into constituent parts:
$ echo "$st" | ruby -lne 'p $_.split("")'
["0", "", "2", "☺", "️", "4", "", "6", "", "8", ""]
                  ^    ^   # should be ONE grapheme

Same if I read that string from a file:
$ cat wee_file
02☺️468

$ ruby -lne 'p $_.split("")' wee_file 
["0", "", "2", "☺", "️", "4", "", "6", "", "8", ""]

Same thing in IRB:
irb(main):001> File.open('/tmp/wee_file').gets.split("")
=> ["0", "", "2", "☺", "️", "4", "", "6", "", "8", "", "\n"]

But if I replace ☺️ with another emoji (which is also multibyte) the issue goes away:
$ st2="02468"
$ echo "$st2" | ruby -lne 'p $_.split("")'
["0", "", "2", "", "4", "", "6", "", "8", ""]

# also from a file and also in IRB..

Any idea why the emoji ☺️ is producing this result?

The others are true single emoji characters, e.g.  is U+1F600 (grinning face), etc. But ☺️ is slotted into U+FE0F (variation selector-16) as a variant of U+263A, the much older smiling face (as your printout shows).

It's because ☺️ is composed of two characters:

☺ U+263A (White Smiling Face)
◌️ U+FE0F (Variation Selector-16)

The latter is used to to request an emoji presentation for the preceding character.
"☺️".codepoints.map { |c| c.to_s(16) }
#=> ["263a", "fe0f"]

You can get the expected result via grapheme_clusters or enumerate them via each_grapheme_cluster:
"02☺️468".grapheme_clusters
#=> ["0", "", "2", "☺️", "4", "", "6", "", "8", ""]


And "02☺️468".scan(/\X/) works as well...

@dawg oh indeed, I wasn't aware that \X is supported by Ruby. It seems to be missing from the docs.

Internally, each_grapheme_cluster in fact seems to be using the regex engine's \X to enumerate the graphemes, see string.c#L9455-L9457 and string.c#L9379

There is also String#grapheme_clusters which returns exactly the same as each_grapheme_cluster.to_a but with fewer intermediate objects.

@HolgerJust must have missed it. I’ve updated the answer accordingly.
